# I am having trouble " using "removeEventListener()"

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

This is the original statement which creates the click handlers.

```
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell")
    cells.forEach(function(cell) {
      cell.addEventListener('click', onCellClicked.bind(this, cell.id));
    })
```

Below I call the `removeEventhandlers()` function which contains the method `removeEventListener()`.
How ever this function does not work and does not produce a error message.
Can anybody help me rectify this problem?

```
if (checkForWin(oSelectionArray) === true) {
    insertWinOrLossImage('ticTacToeAssets/Assets/you win image.png', 'youWin', 'playerScore', wonOrLost = winOrLooseObj.won)
    removeEventHandlers()
  } else if (checkForWin(xSelectionArray) === true) {
    insertWinOrLossImage('ticTacToeAssets/Assets/you loose image.png', 'youLoose', 'CPUscore', wonOrLost = winOrLooseObj.lost)
    removeEventHandlers()
  } else if (oSelectionArray.length === 5) {
      insertWinOrLossImage('ticTacToeAssets/Assets/noWinner.png', 'draw', 'drawScore', wonOrLost = winOrLooseObj.draw)
      removeEventHandlers()
     }
   }

function removeEventHandlers() {
  const cellsToRemoveEventhandlers = document.querySelectorAll(".cell")
  cellsToRemoveEventhandlers.forEach(function(cell) {
    cell.removeEventListener('click', onCellClicked.bind(window));
  })
}
```

Comment: To actually remove the handler, you need a pointer to the function that you added in the first place. `.bind()` will create a new wrapper around the function, so the one you try to remove is not the one you added before. Sidenote: maybe have a look at delegated events - this would only attach one handler to some container as opposed to adding handlers individually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the actual listeners, since `.bind` creates a new function reference.

Something like this:

```
let listeners = {};
const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell")
cells.forEach(function(cell) {
  const listener = onCellClicked.bind(this, cell.id)
  listeners[cell.id] = listener;
  cell.addEventListener('click', listener);
}) 

function removeEventHandlers() {
    const cellsToRemoveEventhandlers = document.querySelectorAll(".cell")
    cellsToRemoveEventhandlers.forEach(function(cell) {
        const listener = listeners[cell.id];
        cell.removeEventListener('click', listener);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `onCellClicked.bind`, you get a newly bound `onCellClicked`, which is different from any earlier binding. This is why `removeEventListener` has nothing to remove.

Instead of adding and removing event listeners dynamically, in your case (tic-tac-toe?) it will probably be better to just keep the events bound and check whether the event listener should do anything *within* the event listener.

The other option is to keep track of the bound event listener functions, but that's more tedious and not worth the while here.

(And one more option is to have the event listener on a parent element and use event bubbling and event delegation.)